# Avoid applying variable to nested Handlebars partial blocks

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a Handlebars partial called "section", defined as following:

```
<div{{#if class}} class="{{class}}"{{/if}}>
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  {{> @partial-block }}
</div>
```

In certain cases I need to use it as follows:

```
{{#> section title="title1" class="class1" }}
  {{#> section title="title2" }}
     <!-- content -->
  {{/ section }}
{{/ section }}
```

The problem is that the "title2" section will also have "class1" resulting in this:

```
<div class="class1">
  <h3>title1</h3>
  <div class="class1">
     <h3>title2</h3>
     <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The question: **is there a way to avoid this, without having to create a second partial e.g. "section_class1"?**

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the data parameters (ex., `title="title1"`) for your partial directly within your template, the simplest way to prevent the nested section partial from inheriting the `class` of its parent would be to explicitly set an empty value for the `class` parameter where the nested partial is declared:

```
{{#> section title="title1" class="class1" }}
  {{#> section title="title2" class="" }}
     <!-- content -->
  {{/ section }}
{{/ section }}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/cau7v0j9/) for reference.

A more robust - and scalable - approach might be to represent your sections in a data structure and pass that to your template. For example, you could define a root section with an array of child sections, like:

```
{
    class: 'class1',
    title: 'First Section',
    sections: [
        {
            class: '',
            title: 'Subsection One'
        },
        {
            class: 'class1',
            title: 'Subsection Two'
        }
    ]
};
```

This gives you the granular control to apply a specific class to each child section.

Your template would then need to iterate over the child `sections` array using an `#each`:

```
{{#> section }}
    {{#each sections }}
        {{#> section this }}
            <!-- content -->
        {{/ section }}
    {{/each}}
{{/ section }}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/0qca9x4s/) demonstrating this alternative.